# Autoregressive distributed lag model

Tags: time-series

Could someone point me in the direction of creating an autoregressive distributed lag model  in mathematica?

Comment: Please also see the "Related" questions shown in the sidebar to this question, particularly [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17620/fitting-data-to-an-arprocess-using-findprocessparameters?rq=1)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are basically two methods.

The first is to use the [`ARProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ARProcess.html) function (or `ARMAProcess` or `ARIMAProcess` as needed) introduced in version 9. The answers to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17620/8) should be helpful.  Here is a small example that modifies the example in the documentation to show how to plot the resulting `TemporalData` using `DateListPlot` rather than `ListPlot`: you have to extract the `"Paths"` attribute.

```
In[50]:= myAR = ARProcess[{0.9, -0.2, 0.15}, 0.8]   
Out[50]= ARProcess[{0.9, -0.2, 0.15}, 0.8]

In[51]:= data = RandomFunction[myAR, {1, 150}]   
Out[51]= TemporalData[1]

In[52]:= DateListPlot[data["Paths"], Joined -> True]
```

[image]

The older pre-version-9 way would be to use some version of [`FoldList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FoldList.html). The trick is that if you are creating an $AR(p)$ process where $p>1$, you need to store the lags initially and then keep only the first elements in each intervening vector, like this

```
 oldfashioned = 
  First /@ FoldList[
    Join[{{0.9, -0.2, 0.15}.#1 + #2}, Most[#1]] &, {0., 0., 0.}, 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 0.8], 150]];

ListLinePlot[oldfashioned, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The advantage of the old way using `FoldList` is that you don't have to assume Gaussian noise. Here is an example with Levy-stable noise:

```
stable = First /@ FoldList[ Join[{{0.9, -0.2, 0.15}.#1 + #2}, Most[#1]] &, {0., 0., 0.}, 
 RandomVariate[StableDistribution[1, 1.1, -0.096, -0.0001, 0.005],  150]];

ListLinePlot[stable, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

If what you mean by "creating" a "model" is to estimate it from data, then I'd suggest the [`EstimatedProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EstimatedProcess.html) function. It does a pretty good job of estimating the AR parameters even with non-Gaussian noise and the "wrong" number of lags.

```
EstimatedProcess[stable, ARProcess[6]]

(* ARProcess[{0.902147, -0.223932,  0.248928, -0.0532185,
  -0.0262434, -0.00263604}, 0.00202357] *)
```

It does even better when you know the order of the underlying AR process.

```
EstimatedProcess[stable, ARProcess[3]]

 (* ARProcess[{0.889943, -0.214266, 0.185013}, 0.0020378] *)
```

Comment: Great thank you!

Comment: In this case you have used an autoregressive AR module, however I do not understand how to get Distributed lags in the model as well.

Comment: If you mean distributed lags of exogenous variables, then you need to respecify the `FoldList` approach to have more than one element in each iterate of the list in the last argument.

Comment: Could you give a example how it would look with two lags of expgenous variables.With the fold list and how a ARDL(2,2) model would look like?